# Could you explain how this current measurement circuit works?

Tags: current, measurement, current-measurement

I have a schematic for current measurement, but I don't really know how can I calculate the output of it. The op-amps are on +-12V. The output of the circuit is 0.2*I(Rs) [V] (--> this is what I don't know how to calculate), thus in the range of 5V, we can measure 25A with it. The V_PWR is 24V.

How should I set this circuit to measure a maximum current of 10A instead of 25A?
What are the diodes and transistors for?

[Circuit measurement schematic http://img5013.photobox.co.uk/151954327f8d9d7d42f253c3a9c42b2e44e8b66e7687b35e9972598d1a88bc7f88b9ef41.jpg](http://img5013.photobox.co.uk/151954327f8d9d7d42f253c3a9c42b2e44e8b66e7687b35e9972598d1a88bc7f88b9ef41.jpg)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEl8c1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks,
Tamas

Comment: We have a builtin circuit editor here, you might want to try that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, the first opamp and the transistor work together to draw a current through the 100Ω resistor such that the voltage drop across it matches the voltage drop across the 0.01Ω sense resistor. Since the former is 10000× the latter, the current through the transistor will be 1/10000 of the sensed current.

The current through the transistor is then fed through the two 1000Ω resistors, which creates a voltage drop of

$$2000\Omega \cdot \frac{I_{LOAD}}{10000} = 0.2 I_{LOAD}$$

The second opamp is just a voltage follower (buffer) for this voltage.

HOWEVER, the circuit cannot work as shown. The two inputs to the first opamp are at a value very close to V_PWR (24V), while the power supply for that opamp is at only ±12V. No opamp can work with its inputs that far outside the supply rails. You should use one of the dedicated current-sensing chips for this part of the circuit, which are specifically designed to deal with this situation.

In order to change the range of operation from 25A to 10A, the simplest thing would be to change the 2K resistance to 5K.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it does work. If the op-amp positive supply is instead connected to the input voltage it could work okay, but not with that amplifier- the input needs to work right up to the positive supply voltage. It's possible that some sneak current paths would cause the thing to sort-of work as shown but I don't think so.

The idea is that the left op-amp will control a current through the 100 ohm resistor to cause the voltage drop across it to equal the voltage drop across the 10m\$\Omega\$ shunt resistor.

Since emitter current of the transistor is almost the same as collector current, that same current flows through the 2K to ground and results in a voltage equal to (approximately) (2K/0.1K)*I*0.01 = 0.2*I. That voltage is buffered by the voltage follower amplifier on the right. I guess the feedback resistor is supposed to be 12K (that's what it should be) but it looks like 1.2K.

There are a few sources of error- the circuit draws a bit of current from the input- the resistor tolerances, and especially op-amp offset voltage at low currents.

The two series diodes are probably there because the designer thought that the op-amp can't get right to the supply voltage at the output (which needs to be close to the input voltage to turn the transistor off). But it doesn't matter with that amplifier since the inputs stop working at a volt or two below the supply voltage. Maybe it was conceived as an application for something like the LT1636- but then you wouldn't need the diodes.

Maybe the person who drew this was having a bad day or doesn't know what the *$*$&* they are doing to begin with. If it worked, you could simply increase the shunt to 25m\$\Omega\$ to get the same voltage out for 10A as the circuit would have for 25A. That would keep the error as a percentage of full scale reading the same as with the 25A circuit (in other words, reduce the error due to op-amp offset voltage by 2.5:1). You could do as @Dave suggests and increase the 1K + 1K load resistor if you're not concerned about accuracy at low currents.

TL;DR: This kind of circuit puts unusual demands on the op-amps used. If you want to do this, instead of using a regular op-amp consider buying a current measuring circuit that has a low Vos/TCVos amplifier with the proper input common mode range (including the positive rail) and current source transistor all in one little part and add the shunt, load resistor and buffer amplifier yourself.